# Using SDL2 and OpenGL to rotate camera and a triangle draw wont display anything?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2, glm-math, gl-matrix

I am simply trying to create a triangle in the center and rotate the camera around the center. `(0,0,0)`.  the code is whipped from multiple tutorial sources and i suspect the problem could be somewhere from the `glm::perspective/lookat` or `gl:projection/model matrix` before triangle draw calls.
because that's where my general confusion is at right now.
any help is greatly appreciated so i can move on with my life. thank you in advance.

```
//sudo g++ -o sdl main.cpp -lSDL2_image -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lX11 -lGLEW `sdl2-config --cflags --libs`
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <string>
#include <GL/gl.h>



std::string programName = "SDL2/OpenGL";
SDL_Window *mainWindow;
SDL_GLContext mainContext;

void Calculate()
{
    float radius = 2.0f;
    float camX = sin(SDL_GetTicks()*0.001) * radius;
    float camZ = cos(SDL_GetTicks()*0.001) * radius;

    glm::mat4 perspecive_mat = glm::perspective(
        45.0f, 1.0f / 1.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f );

    glm::mat4 view_mat = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(camX, 0.0, camZ), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0) );

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrixf(glm::value_ptr(perspecive_mat));

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadMatrixf(glm::value_ptr(view_mat));
}


void Render()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

    float vertexCoords[24] = {  // Coordinates for the vertices of a cube.
               1,1,1,   1,1,-1,   1,-1,-1,   1,-1,1,
              -1,1,1,  -1,1,-1,  -1,-1,-1,  -1,-1,1  };

    float vertexColors[24] = {  // An RGB color value for each vertex
               1,1,1,   1,0,0,   1,1,0,   0,1,0,
               0,0,1,   1,0,1,   0,0,0,   0,1,1  };

    int elementArray[24] = {  // Vertex numbers for the six faces.
              0,1,2,3, 0,3,7,4, 0,4,5,1,
              6,2,1,5, 6,5,4,7, 6,7,3,2  };

    glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexCoords );
    glColorPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexColors );

    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glEnableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );

    glDrawElements( GL_QUADS, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, elementArray );


    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(mainWindow);
}

bool Loop()
{
    while (true ){
        SDL_Event event;
        while ( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) ){
            switch ( event.type ){
                case SDL_QUIT :
                SDL_Quit();
                return 0;
                case SDL_KEYDOWN : 
                    std::cout<<"Key Down"<<std::endl;
                    break;
                case SDL_KEYUP :
                    std::cout<<"Key Up"<<std::endl;
                    break;
                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP :
                case SDL_MOUSEMOTION :
                default :
                    break;
            }
        }

        Calculate();

        Render();
    }
}


void CheckSDLError(int line = -1){
    std::string error = SDL_GetError();

    if (error != "")
    {
        std::cout << "SLD Error : " << error << std::endl;

        if (line != -1)
            std::cout << "\nLine : " << line << std::endl;

        SDL_ClearError();
    }
}


void Cleanup(){
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(mainContext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(mainWindow );
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0){
        std::cout << "Failed to init SDL\n";
        return false;
    }
    mainWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(programName.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,512, 512, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (!mainWindow )
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to create window\n"<< std::endl;;
        CheckSDLError(__LINE__);
        return false;
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    //SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_COMPATIBILITY);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    mainContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(mainWindow );

    // This makes our buffer swap syncronized with the monitor's vertical refresh
    //      ( which means it enables v-sync)
    // Setting this to 0 will disable V-sync
    //      Which means our application could run at unlimited fps
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);
    // Init GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; 
    glewInit();
    // Enable blending so that we can have transparanet object
    glEnable(GL_BLEND ) ;
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    // Enable depth testing so that closer triangles will hide the triangles farther away
    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    Loop();
    Cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, that drawing by `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences and the fixed function pipeline matrix stack is deprecated since decades.
Read about [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and see [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) for a state of the art way of rendering.

If you want to use the deprecated way of drawing, then you have to use a compatibility profile context instead of a core profile context (see [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context)):

<s>`SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);`</s>
`SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_COMPATIBILITY);`

---

Further note, that [`glm::lookAt`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00668.html#gaa64aa951a0e99136bba9008d2b59c78e) and [`glm::perspective`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00665.html#ga747c8cf99458663dd7ad1bb3a2f07787) don't set any OpenGL states or even fixed function pipline matrices. [glm - OpenGL Mathematics](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/index.html) is a math library, to do calculations related to OpenGL. Both function return a 4*4 matrix.

You can use [`glLoadMatrixf`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadMatrix.xml) to load a matrix return by a *glm* function to the OpenGL fixed function pipeline matrix stack:

```cpp
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
```

```cpp
void Calculate()
{
    float radius = 2.0f;
    float camX = sin(SDL_GetTicks()*0.001) * radius;
    float camZ = cos(SDL_GetTicks()*0.001) * radius;

    glm::mat4 perspecive_mat = glm::perspective(
        45.0f, 1.0f / 1.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f );

    glm::mat4 view_mat = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(camX, 0.0, camZ), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0) );

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadMatrixf(glm::value_ptr(perspecive_mat));

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadMatrixf(glm::value_ptr(view_mat));
}
```

---

If you want to use a core profile, then you have to create a simple [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) program:

```cpp
#include <string>

std::string sh_vert = R"(
#version 150 core

in vec3 v_pos;
in vec4 v_col;

out vec4 color;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;

void main()
{
    color = v_col;                    
    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(v_pos, 1.0);
} 
)";

std::string sh_frag = R"(
#version 150 core

in vec4 color;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = color;
} 
)";
```

Compile and link the program:

```cpp
#include <vector>

GLuint CreateShader(GLenum type, const char *code)
{
    GLuint shaderObj = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(shaderObj, 1, &code, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(shaderObj);

    GLint status = GL_TRUE;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderObj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint logLen;
        glGetShaderiv(shaderObj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLen);
        std::vector< char >log(logLen);
        GLsizei written;
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderObj, logLen, &written, log.data());
        std::cout << "compile error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
    }
    return shaderObj;
}

GLuint CreateProgram()
{
    GLuint vShObj = CreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, sh_vert.c_str());
    GLuint fShObj = CreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, sh_frag.c_str());

    GLuint progObj = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(progObj, vShObj);
    glAttachShader(progObj, fShObj);
    glLinkProgram(progObj);

    GLint status = GL_TRUE;
    glGetProgramiv(progObj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint logLen;
        glGetProgramiv(progObj, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLen);
        std::vector< char >log(logLen);
        GLsizei written;
        glGetProgramInfoLog(progObj, logLen, &written, log.data());
        std::cout << "link error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
    }
    return progObj;
}
```

Get the attribute and uniform locations:

```cpp
GLuint prog;
GLint pos_attr, col_attr, proj_loc, view_loc;

void Init()
{
    prog = CreateProgram();
    pos_attr = glGetAttribLocation(prog, "v_pos");
    col_attr = glGetAttribLocation(prog, "v_col");
    proj_loc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "projection");
    view_loc = glGetUniformLocation(prog, "view");

    // ....

 }
```

Create a [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object):

```cpp
GLuint vao;

void Init()
{
    // ....

    const std::vector<float> varray
    {
    // x      y     z     red   green blue
      -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
       0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
       0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, varray.size()*sizeof(float), varray.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glVertexAttribPointer(pos_attr, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6*sizeof(float), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos_attr);
    glVertexAttribPointer(col_attr, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6*sizeof(float), (void*)(3*sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(col_attr);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Installs the program object as part of current rendering state and set the uniform variables:

```cpp
void Calculate()
{
    float radius = 2.0f;
    float camX = sin(SDL_GetTicks()*0.001) * radius;
    float camZ = cos(SDL_GetTicks()*0.001) * radius;

    glm::mat4 perspecive_mat = glm::perspective(
        45.0f, 1.0f / 1.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f );

    glm::mat4 view_mat = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(camX, 0.0, camZ), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0) );

    glUseProgram(prog);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(perspecive_mat));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(view_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view_mat));
}
```

Finally draw the triangle:

```cpp
void Render()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(mainWindow);
}

bool Loop()
{
    Init();

    while (true) {
        // ....

        Calculate();
        Render();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for  your suggestion i updated the code to use glDrawElements insted of glBegin-glEnd. but still no results. can you maybe give it a go, if you can. much appreciated.

Comment: on it. thank you and let u know as soon as i have something.

Comment: ohh mann. works like a charm. cant thank you enough coz i was loosing sleep over this and almost about to switch back to freeglut. not that i understand it completely but now i have the ground to break and proceed from here. really appreciate it. thank you.

Comment: maybe you can look at this @Rabbid76 ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56914940/drawing-textured-cube-in-android-ndk-using-opengl-es2-will-not-draw-anything